# Troubleshooting AOS in Next.js 13: Seeking Solutions for Proper Functionality

Tags: javascript, animation, next.js, aos.js, animate-on-scroll

I have a multiple divs that needs to appear in animated form when it reaches the viewport. It is not like AOS is not working but the div only appear when they reach around the top section or mid section of viewport which makes it seem as if the div is blank. This happens when the page is accessed first time or reloaded, it seems to be working fine when redirecting from another page. How can I solve this? Also is there another library which can do same as AOS?

I tried refresh function, initialize after the contents of the page is loaded, setTimeOut to initialize AOS after certain time. None of them seems to be working, only time it is working is when redirecting from another page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.